# Search goes to admin/products in stead of the product page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, search-engine

I'm working on a search site on a drupal 7 page.
The standard search module is set to Commerce Search at the moment.
But I also have the possibilities of  Display Suite Search and node.
The thing is that I have ordinary products and then I have attributes and a subproduct. And when I search in nodes the subproducts won´t show.

When I search for the product and subproduct, they all show up with the commerce search, but the 
link of the teaser goes to admin/commerce instead of the product page??? Totally lost here.
The link: http://botved.dk/search/product/35895

And also, where can I change the view of the search? I've tried to install the devel-themer module, but it seems to be expired, so if anyone knows a similar module, where you can see where the code is in templates.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
The Display Suite module has a wonderful method for taking control of search results: It will allow you to easily use your teasers in search results. [This is a tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rn3e91C_2jw) by the maintainer of the module that focuses on using it for search results.
```

Search module in Drupal is an internal site search system but in Drupal 7 you can use.. 
[template_preprocess_search_results](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_results/7)

[template_preprocess_search_results](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_results/7)

to theme with the information displayed in the results.
And you can use

[search-results.tpl.php and](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-results.tpl.php/7)

[search-result.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-result.tpl.php/7)

to customize the markup of the results.